# Why the values are not evaluated in the html when using pipe?

Tags: angular, pipe, subscribe

I am using a pipe to do the currency conversion, the values are not evaluated in HTML.

Here is my pipe

```
transform(value: number, selectedCurrency: string, baseCurrency: string): number {
    if (selectedCurrency && baseCurrency) {
        let outputRate = this.currencyStorage.getCurrencyRate(baseCurrency, selectedCurrency);
        if (outputRate !== null) {
            this.currencyConversion.getExchangeRate(selectedCurrency, baseCurrency).subscribe((rate: any) => {
                let currency = { 'fromCurrency': baseCurrency, 'toCurrency': selectedCurrency, 'exchangeRate': rate };
                this.currencyStorage.saveCurrencies(currency);
                return value * rate;
            }, (error: any) => this.errorMessage = error);
        } else {
            return value * outputRate;
        }
    }
};
```

and my HTML

```
   <span> {{listitem.value  | inclCommission  | currConvert:selectedCurrency:listitem.currency}</span>
```

Is it because i am getting the rate using a api service and subscribing inside the pipe? how can i change this to make it work?

Comment: Are `getCurrencyRate()` and `getExchangeRate()` synchronous or do they make an HTTP request to a server?

Comment: getExchangeRate make request to server and getCurrencyRate is synchronous

Comment: I see. I missed the `subscribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing `return`

```
return this.currencyConversion.getExchangeRate(...
```

and add the `| async` pipe:

```
<span> {{listitem.value  | inclCommission  | currConvert:selectedCurrency:listitem.currency | async}}</span>
```

**update**

`subscribe(...)` needs to be changed to `.map(...)`

Comment: only this change?

Comment: You also need to add the `| async pipe`. I updated my answer.

Comment: No still i dont see the value in HTML , please help

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging on your own. Print to `console.log(...)` what the values are that are passed to the pipe, also assign values to variables and print them to the console before returning them. If you can't track it down this way yourself, please add the information to your question and leave a comment, then I'll have another look.

Comment: it print the values in both places , is it the problem with line  return value * rate;

Comment: Hard to tell from here. If the values are actually returned, they will be added to the HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150593/discussion-between-face-turn-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at Error

Comment: any idea on this ?

Comment: You can try to `return Promise.resolve(value);` instead of just `return value;` if the returned value is not an `Observable`. Your error message indicates that you return an array that contains a single object value. I wouldn't expect this to display properly in HTML.

Comment: Please try to reproduce in a Plunker. I don't see a way to debug your problem with these information fragments.

Comment: can you come to the chat?

Comment: Did changing `subscribe` to `map` fix the problem?